# Content-Type of client request in SignalR (Silverlight client)

Tags: request, signalr, url-encoding

Using SignalR Silverlight client, the request to server is not JSON. Actually, it is JSON but it is UrlEncoded as value of field "data", something like this (POST payload):

```
data=%7b%22I%22%3a%220%22%2c%22H%22%3a%22s3Hub%22%2c%22M%22%3a%22notify%22%2c%22A%22%3a...
```

with header

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

This is not what I can easily visually check in tools like Fiddler. The response is OK - JSON as I'd expected. How could I configure the client to use application/json as Content-Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Today we send a form urlencoded payload to the server. In a future version we might send via JSON. It's an implementation detail that really shouldn't affect your application.

Comment: Well, it's detail until you don't debug your application and need to heavily check requests and responses :-) OK, thanks anyway